# Is there a precedent for NPCs knowing that the PCs are controlled by players?

Tags: adventure-writing, metagaming

I've just read [*NPCs* by Drew Hayes](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/22088245-npcs) and it gave me an idea for a plot in which the NPCs in the game world somehow know that the PCs are characters being controlled by other people.

Is there any precedent in RPGs for this kind of story?

Comment: (Not the Drew Hayes of *[Poison](http://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/5102/8610) [Elves](http://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/62245/8610)* fame, rest his soul.)

Comment: So a few things to know first.

Are the PC's themselves aware that they are being controlled by other people?

If the NPC's are aware of that the PC's are being controlled, do they know if they are being controlled and if so;

Do they think the have their own 'player'?
OR
Do they know they are all controlled by the same person (GM)?

Comment: @Kalcipher23 in the book the PCs are like puppets they have no consciousness of their own. It is some of the NPCs who begin to realise that these "adventurers" are "not of this world". (Trying to give as few spoilers as is possible) As far as the NPCs are concerned, they are their own beings. They live in the world they are in and have their own lives, they are not controlled by the GM... (according to the NPCs) they wouldn't even know what a GM is. :-)

Comment: @Fogmeister Finally why are you trying to establish precedent? Anything can happen in an RPG, it doesn't have to have been done before. Or would it be more accurate to assume you are looking for ideas to run this kind of game?

Comment: What sort of precedent are you looking for? For example, I know a story like this, does that count? Or are you looking for a game with rules about this?